# How to divide a sentence to words and compare with another string?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, compare

I have saved the units in .txt file. These I am getting in an array list. Now I want to check if any of the units present in the string.

List contains :

`"units", "kg", "kilogms", "kilo", "literes", 
"Liter", "packets", "packet", "gms", "grams", "half kg"`

Like, if I have a string - 1kg rice, I want to get numbers from this string and I want to divide this sentence to words and want to compare with each item from array list of units. If it is present I want to save it. So I want to store 1kg and rice separately. string may contain any spaces I want to trim all those spaces and check compare.

Getting text file in an array list.

```
    public class ReadTextFiles {

    public static List<String> readItemNamesFile(Context context) {
        String sText = null;
        List<String> stringList;
        try{

            InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.item_names);
            //Use one of the above as per your file existing folder

            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            sText = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

            String[] sTextArray = sText.replace("\"", "").split(",");
            stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sTextArray));
            System.out.print(stringList);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return stringList;

    }
}

 public void getUnits()
{
    List<String> units = new ArrayList<>();

    units = ReadTextFiles.readUnitsFile(getActivity());

    System.out.print(units.size());

}
```

Now I want to compare string suppose its "1 kg potato".Then should find potato from the array list. Also it should be case insensitive.

Comment: If you have control over your data, I would recommend moving to more complex structure like JSON or XML.

Comment: sorry did not get you. @RomanKolomenskii

Comment: Why JSON and XML are considered as complex structure  @RomanKolomenskii?

Comment: Well, JSON like `{"quantity" : 1, "measure" : "kg", "name" : "potato"}` is much safer than some string formatted with spaces

Comment: I am not getting data in json format, Only in string format.@RomanKolomenskii

Comment: my question was why are you saying json and xml are complex?

Comment: As I understood that you want to find out item, measuring unit and quantity from string like "1kg rice", check readyandroid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the full solution of your requirement as I understood:

```
    String measuring = "\"units\", \"kg\", \"kilogms\", \"kilo\", \"literes\", \"Liter\", \"packets\", \"packet\", \"gms\", \"grams\", \"half kg\"";
    String items = "\"Potato\", \"rice\", \"Eggs\", \"Maggi\", \"Dryfruits\", \"Maza\", \"cold drink\", \"sauce\", \"catchup\", \"coconut oil\"";
    String matching = "Kg500 Potato";//"Potato 1 kg";
    String item = "", measuringUnit = "", quantity = "";

    private void findOut() {
        String[] sMeasuringArray = measuring.replace("\"", "").split(", ");
        ArrayList<String> measuringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sMeasuringArray));

        String[] sItemsArray = items.replace("\"", "").split(", ");
        ArrayList<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sItemsArray));

        String[] sMatchingArray = matching.split(" ");

        matching = matching.toUpperCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < measuringList.size(); i++) {
            if (matching.contains(measuringList.get(i).toUpperCase())) {
                measuringUnit = measuringList.get(i).trim();
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
            if (matching.contains(itemsList.get(i).toUpperCase())) {
                item = itemsList.get(i).trim();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matching!= null) {
            String[] part = matching.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
            for (int k = 0; k < part.length; k++) {
                try {
                    Integer.parseInt(part[k]);
                    quantity = part[k];
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        /*if (sMatchingArray != null) {
            if (sMatchingArray.length == 3) {
                for (int j = 0; j < sMatchingArray.length; j++) {
                    if (measuringUnit.trim().equals(sMatchingArray[j].trim())) {
                        quantity = sMatchingArray[j - 1].trim();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (sMatchingArray.length == 2) {

                String[] part = matching.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
                for (int k = 0; k < part.length; k++) {
                    try {
                        Integer.parseInt(part[k]);
                        quantity = part[k];
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/

        Log.e("Solution: ", "item = " + item + ", measuringUnit = " + measuringUnit + ", quantity = " + quantity);
    }
```

Comment: only measuring unit kg I got not the quantity and item.

Comment: You didn't get item because in my code sample matching string is "1 kg potato"which is in in small letter but in items list it is like "Potato". And for quantity let me check.

Comment: and if space isn't given its not working. I did for quantity extracted only numbers from the string. now just if string is 500gms rice then it is not searching for gms same for item name.

Comment: why that last if and elseif is used? we get the unit and item in for loops only.

Comment: These at last if and if else are used for same case as you mentioned 500gms rice, let me check

Comment: also if wrote in Caps it dose not find like Rice or Gms it should be case insensitive.

Comment: Tell me all the cases in which your matching string can be and it's matching scenarios, if you tell one by one then it's not possible to get an output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130412/discussion-between-sid-and-ready-android).

Comment: Just these all I told for spaces and case sensitivity.

Comment: Check latest answer I think it will cover all cases.

Comment: its still not checking with spaces and caps letters. I am getting array like this :  ArrayList<String> measuringList = new ArrayList<String>(ReadTextFiles.readUnitsFile(getActivity()));

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna be using algorithmic approach for the answer. So here it goes:

```
strItem = "1kg rice";
//Run a loop through the list of units and for each unit check this
if (strItem.contains(list.get(index)))
 //Do the needful and break
```

Comment: but string index can be anything. Like "1kg rice" or "rice 1 kg".

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Well, to do that then you don't have to split the string. Just checking it for the units will do it.

Comment: and suppose if I want to check same for the item name i.e rice? Can you give me example.

Comment: Just compare it with a list having the item names.

Comment: If the string contains `background`, should it find `kg` in it? (`bac` + `kg` + `round`) @Sid

Comment: no, string would be any item name and the unite and quantity. So I want to separate all 3. @OleV.V.